# What is causing this AUCTeX preview fatal error, or how can I find that out?

Tags: auctex, osx, preview-latex

This is a minimal test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[1+1=2\]
\end{document}
```

The content of texput.log is the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.7)  23 OCT 2019 23:49
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage,auctex}{preview}\AtBeginDocument{\ifx\ifPreview\undefined\RequirePackage[displaymath,floats,graphics,textmath,sections,footnotes]{preview}[2004/11/05]\fi} \input {\detokenize{ _region_.tex }}^^M

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

<*> ...5]\fi} \input {\detokenize{ _region_.tex }}
                                                  ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8 strings out of 492166
 160 string characters out of 6125377
 59039 words of memory out of 5000000
 4473 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5i,0n,6p,268b,10s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The problem appeared after one time I ran `brew upgrade` in terminal. I guess it is because the latest ghostscript has some incompatibility issue with AUCTeX. I have searched a lot and tried a lot. Here are what I have done:

1. I use Mac. There is a known problem with the path of ghostscript. This line is in my init file: `(setq preview-gs-command "/usr/local/bin/gs")`. It should be correct.
2. I have tried to manually install old versions of ghostscript, like 9.21 or 9.25. They used to solve the problem, but not this time.
3. I uninstalled ghostscript installed with brew and manually installed 9.25. Not working.

System: MacOS Catalina 10.15
Emacs: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02
AUCTeX: 12.1.2
ghostscript: 9.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time the culprit is not GS but the latest updates to LaTeX kernel.  This issue is fixed in [AUCTeX repo](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=eafb11477c08531b823de387f7bdf0b5f8b4a4dd).  Just wait for the new AUCTeX release which should happen quit soon and install it from ELPA then.

Comment: I noted that the format loading message is missing in the output and the `%&-line parsing enabled`-thing. Looks like [`-parse-first-line`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172812/what-is-line-parsing-enabled) is enabled but the actual magic comment is missing in the LaTeX file.

Comment: Finally, I modified preview.el according to the commit information and byte-compiled it. This fixed my problem. Thanks!